# Multi requests on Tomcat 7 and Jersey RESTful web services

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, rest, tomcat

I created with Tomcat 7 and Jersey (Java) a simple web services. In each API, I use PhantomJs to simulate web browsing.

I was wondering what is the best solution to industrialize this product, for example, suppose you have 300-400 simultaneous requests to the API provided by the web services and will have access to a server with 4 Xeon processors each with 8 cores and 16 threads, with 64 GB RAM and 600 GB of storage.

I have to use thread pools with Tomcat? or another solution?

Comment: Are you asking how to scale the web service ? That question is quite generic and the answer will encompass one of many thumb rules you can follow / tools you can use to get there.

Comment: sorry, my question was, when they have a good multi-core servers etc etc. .. to solve my problem I have to focus on to best configure Tomcat? or am I wrong road?

Comment: There is no simple answer to your question. You'll first need to load test your service to determine parameters such as throughput and response times. Then you work out how much load each instance can take and configure other parameters appropriately. You're trying to solve this the other way about. You cannot tweak parameters without knowing what you are tweaking them for.

Comment: thanks!you're right! i wanted to know if I'm going towards one possible solution or not; i was thinking for tomcat clustering with nginx for load balancer

Answer (score 0):

Normally it depends on your user case, e.g: is it call to a database or it just do something in memory and return. The generic rule is "more threads doesn't equal to better thruput"

Comment: for example, if i set Connectors in Tomcat, and each incoming request requires a thread for the duration of that request, i have one instance of PhantomJs for all requests?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Comsat](https://github.com/puniverse/comsat) - it will allow you to create as many (lightweight) threads on Tomcat/Jersey as you need.

Comment: I am one of the co-founders that develop this library :) Feel free to get in touch

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how "PhantomJs works". 
Generally speaking, it based on your throughput expecation and how many servers by your hand.

The suggestions i think are:

1. Find a way to evaluate your application (Nagios, JMX, whatever)
2. Choose a extensible solution, once you find there has the throuput issue, you have way to update.
3. Start simple, find a container that can well integrate with any RESTFul framework. Google the doc and to see if there has references and blogs.

check out this: Enable Async support (NIO) for Jersey in Tomcat: http://peter-braun.org/2013/04/asynchronous-processing-from-servlet-3-0-to-jax-rs-2-0/